# URL encoding in Swift

Tags: swift, url, google-places-api, endpoint

Im considering using Google Places API to fetch places nearby given coordinates. One example URL Google provides is the following: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

What is the best and safest way to construct `URL` for such an endpoint? If I initialize `URL` with a `String`, do I need to worry about the numbers/coords being in string format? Does `UrlComponents` class handle this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `URL(string: string)` for this kind of url and set your values into the parameter. Like this:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-\(lat),\(long)&radius=\(radius)&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=\(apiKey)")
```

If you for example want to hardcode the `radius` value you just do it like this instead:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-\(lat),\(long)&radius=500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=\(apiKey)")
```